# Is there an equivalent of ctags or cscope for browsing R code in R using ESS mode?

Tags: r, emacs, ctags, ess

For c++ and c I am able to create TAGS file by running ctags -e or use cscope to navigate a codebase in emacs. Is there an equivalent for a codebase in R? ctags ignored my R files...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See

```
R --help|grep tags
R CMD rtags --help
```

and within R `?rtags`